# Why my fltk program compiles but doesn't run?

Tags: c++, user-interface, fluid, fltk

I am trying to build a game program in fltk which solves puzzles and it includes a GUI. My code compiles fine but the program doesn't run and the GUI never starts. I use this line to compile: 
`g++ main.cpp` `'fltk-config --cxxflags --libs --ldflags.'` 
It generates a file called a.out. I tried to use different versions of fltk but still it does not help. Is it a problem with my makefile?

Thanks in advance!

Your help would be appreciated

Comment: Does your LD_LIBRARY_PATH contain the directory where libfltk.so and its buddies live?

Comment: Type ldd followed by your program name - does it tell you that anything is missing?